# add 2d arraylist to 3d arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have got 3d arraylist and to each dimension of it I want to add a temporary 2d arraylists. For example

```
   List<List<Integer>> perm = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   List<List<List<Integer>>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<List<Integer>>>();
   list1.get(0).add(perm);
   list1.get(1).add(perm);
```

but this one does not work. It tells me

```
   The method add(List<Integer>) in the type List<List<Integer>> is not applicable for the    
   arguments (List<List<Integer>>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the types more closely - you're trying to add a `List<List<Integer>>` to the first list inside `list1` (because you've called `get(0)`.)

This first list (inside the topmost `ArrayList`) however is of type `List<Integer>`, not `List<List<Integer>>` - thus the types don't match, and you get a compile error.

Comment: @user3758223 It depends what you're trying to achieve - just doing `list1.add(perm);` would compile, though I've no idea if that's the behaviour that you're after.

Comment: well I want to add various temporary 2d lists into the dimensions of the 3d list. So for example when I call System.out.print(list1.get(0)) I get one 2d list like [1,2,3],[5,2,1] and System.out.print(list1.get(1)) will give me another list like [0,0,1],[2,2,2] and so on.